# CakePHP 3 SMTP TLS configuration

Tags: cakephp, smtp, cakephp-3.0, starttls

I have a problem with connecting to email server through SMTP with encryption (ssl with tls). It is Kerio Connect service where the connection worked for years and suddenly stopped after update. I tried both ports 25 and 465. I tried ssl both with tls and without but nothing worked for me. Certificate is correct and everything worked a few hours ago. I have no idea what else to try. The error messages I get are:

error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

**EDIT:** Maybe it could be the version of TLS but I did not find any option to force TLS1.2 to check if it helps.

Comment: You say it stopped working "after update". What was updated?

Comment: The Kerio Connect service was updated, so I just assume it has something to do with that. I think it can need TLS1.2 but Cake connects with TLS1.0 or TLS1.1 but did not find where to change that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case to force TLS 1.2 with **CakePHP 3.3**, I fixed the issue by editing the following file:

app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Socket.php line 91

Replace **STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT** with **STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT**

You must be using at least **php 5.6** and **openssl 1.0.1**. I hope this helps.